Download Github artifact via curl within github action gives 'Could not resolve host: .'
Given the following github action:
name: MyPipeline

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  # Required for release
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    outputs:
      artifact-url: ${{ steps.artifact-upload-step.outputs.artifact-url }}
    steps:
      # Other steps ommitted

      - name: Upload Artifact
        id: artifact-upload-step
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: MyArtifact
          path: ./output/
          if-no-files-found: error
          
  publish:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Use API because download artifact action will unzip the artifact, but we want to keep it zipped
      - name: Download artifact using curl
        run: >
          curl -L --no-progress-meter --fail-with-body 
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" 
          -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" 
          -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" 
          -O "./output/MyArtifact.zip"
          "${{ needs.build.outputs.artifact-url }}"
        shell: bash

Curl gives the error:
Could not resolve host: .
If I echo ${{ steps.artifact-upload-step.outputs.artifact-url }} in the publish job, I see my correct artifact URL. (And can download it via browser)
Step output:
Run curl -L --no-progress-meter --fail-with-body  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"  -H "Authorization: ***"  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"  -O "./output/MyArtifact.zip"  "https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo/actions/runs/10293145930/artifacts/1788063174"
  curl -L --no-progress-meter --fail-with-body  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"  -H "Authorization: ***"  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"  -O "./output/MyArtifact.zip"  "https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo/actions/runs/10293145930/artifacts/1788063174"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
  env:
    VERSION: 1.0.0.12
    DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Not Found

I also tried to create a URL to access the API:
"${{ github.api_url }}/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/artifacts/${{ needs.build.outputs.artifact-id }}/zip"

Which gives:
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .


Do you use your self-hosted runners?

The correct way to download an artifact in an action is to use the actions/download-artifact action. There shouldn't be any need to download the artifact via curl:
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: MyArtifact
          path: ./output/          
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./output -r


I want to download an artifact and upload it to release. The download-artifact action will always un-archive the artifact, meaning I need to re-archive it.

I'm not sure where you get the info that download-artifact will un-archive an artifact. Nowhere in the documentation for the action does it mention archive. An artifact can be downloaded multiple times, without needing to be re-uploaded (either manually or automatically). I'll happily amend my answer if I can see where you're coming from.

https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/issues/143#issuecomment-1557645216

Just to clarify, it sounds like you want to download the artifact so that you can upload it to the built-in github releases page for your repo. Could you just use this to rezip it for the release upload (see added 'Zip artifact for deployment' step in my answer)

I could, but unzipping and re-zipping is exactly what I am trying to avoid. (Github bills per minute, waste of time and money)
